# How did Stack Overflow create the star sparkle mouse trail effect?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, time-machine

I love the star sparkle mouse trail effect that Stack Overflow used for April Fools' Day.

How did the Stack Overflow developers create this effect?

If I want to continue using this after April Fools' Day, would it be possible for Stack Overflow to open-source the code? Is there a user-script that will enable this permanently?

Comment: Try going into the developer tools to look at the website's code.

Comment: They may have been inspired by *[HTML5 Canvas Tutorials for Beginners | Become a Canvas Pro](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpPnRKq7eNW3We9VdCfx9fprhqXHwTPXL)* (8 parts) - [17 seconds into the first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO6OkltgudE&t=17).

Comment: There's actually a userscript on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8289/cursor-decorations-based-on-the-april-fools-2019-theme)